# google spreadsheet CellNotFound Exception using python issue

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, discord.py

I am building Discord bot which ask user for their name and Points. My spreadsheet has two columns with first raw as header (Name, Points). my code take the name of the player and search the spreadsheet if found update the point. This works perfect when the player name already found but i get cellnotfound error when the name is not in the google sheet.

i have already tried solution in other forum but non are working like
if len(cells) > 0 and  except gspread.exceptions.CellNotFound:  and except gspread.CellNotFound:

```
import gspread
from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials
from pprint import pprint
from googleapiclient import discovery


# SET UP GSHEETS DESTINATION
scope =["https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds",'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets',"https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file","https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive"]

creds = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name("generated.json", scope)
client1 = gspread.authorize(creds)
content = "22"
if content.isdigit():
 #open spreadsheet
 sh = client1.open("test")
 worksheet = sh.sheet1
 nameof= 'player4'
 #find data with playername
 cells = worksheet.find(nameof)
 if cells != []:
  #capture player name data column and row number
  #print("found at R%s  C%s" %(cells.row, cells.col))
  name_row_number = ("%s"%(cells.row))
  name_cell_number = ("%s"%(cells.col))
  old_points_cell_number = int(name_cell_number)+1
  #print(old_points_cell_number)
  oldscore = worksheet.cell(name_row_number, old_points_cell_number).value
  #print(oldscore)
  worksheet.update_cell(name_row_number, old_points_cell_number, content)
 else:
   print("name not found")
```

[Screenshot of my google sheet][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/iw6O5.png

Below is the error message i get

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\gspread\models.py", line 1799, in find
    return self._finder(finditem, query, in_row, in_column)
  File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\gspread\models.py", line 1761, in _finder
    return func(match, cells)
  File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\gspread\utils.py", line 97, in finditem
    return next((item for item in seq if func(item)))
StopIteration

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\abc\Desktop\Discord_Python\ReadExcel.py", line 38, in <module>
    cells = worksheet.find(nameof)
  File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\gspread\models.py", line 1801, in find
    raise CellNotFound(query)
gspread.exceptions.CellNotFound: player4
```

Comment: Some of the code needs tabulation like isdigit. Is that causing the error or is just a post mistake?

Comment: i was able to find solution for my query issue but now having cellnotfound error